# Online tool for minyan management?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, internet, synagogue, minyan

If I'm running a small [minyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minyan) that sometimes has a quorum and sometimes doesn't, and I'd like to only hold the minyan when I know we'll have ten, is there an online tool to help me manage this?

Comment: There used to be an online service available called RoboGabbai. The website no longer works, but you can see the services they provided on the wayback machine:  http://web.archive.org/web/20080706130816/http://www.robogabbai.com/

Comment: I have [this](https://www.rustybrick.com/android-minyan.php) but have never used it, though it does look like it might help you here....announce in advance that you'll put out a call for a minyan at the same time every day, and y'all respond if you're coming.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.minyanman.co.za/ is a Minyan management tool.

> Minyan Manager is a community service to help people manage business
>   minyanim. We know how useful it is having a mincha minyan at work but
>   how time consuming it is to manage it, as well as how frustrating when
>   people come and yet a minyan is not present. We hope this will reduce
>   the administration and encourage more companies to have a mincha
>   minyan. For more information contact info@minyanman.co.za

Comment: +1 Can you include some details about the features it offers?

Answer (score 8):

[JPal](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jpalapp/jpal-worlds-first-smart-synagogue-platform) should solve this issue.

Please check this thread on SE: [Davening with a Minyan in China](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85882/davening-with-a-minyan-in-china)

**Details:**

> [Minyan On Demand](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jpalapp/jpal-worlds-first-smart-synagogue-platform)  let's you create a minyan anywhere in the world and
>   instantly have thousands of users notified. Ideal for international
>   business travels and anyone looking to pray with a minyan where
>   there's no permanent minyan available.

Comment: You should give some more details as to how this solves the problem rather than just leaving it as a link.

Comment: @sabbahillel updated.

Answer (score 5):

You might try Google Calendar; this way you can invite folks, and their responses will be shown in the meeting entry for each tefillah. Of course, this assumes that people live up to their responses!

Comment: Often getting those who said they would come to come is a very great challenge.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a Facebook page for your Minyan and send out Minyan times on a daily basis to people who voluntarily subscribe, and then ask participants to reply by a certain time if they plan to attend.

Answer (score 3):

https://synago.io does this:

> This is Synago. Automagic minyan planning and scheduling of synagogue services in the diaspora.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.doodle.com/ is a good resource for organizing peoples' schedules