# Davening with a Minyan in China

Tags: tefilla, technology, synagogue, minyan

I regularly travel to China (and other countries) for business purposes. I know there are other Jewish travelers who do the same which I sometimes meet on the way. I think that if we have the right system in place we could easily daven with a minyan. However, it is difficult to reach out to each person and make the right connections so everyone is at the same place, at the same time.

Is there anything that can be done to automate this process?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52/759

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/qry/china/jewish/Centers.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if there's such a system available at the moment but I came across a project on Kickstarter  [ [JPal](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jpalapp/jpal-worlds-first-smart-synagogue-platform) ] that aims to automate this process.

According to the developers people can create a minyan "on demand" and have users who plan on being in the area notified of the new minyan. The app tracks participants in real time and displays all the relevant information to potential participants.

Here's a screenshot of the app:

[image: JPal APP - Minyan On Demand]

I know that in the past there were some other websites that performed this functionality but they are no longer working at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my analysis it seems you can choose from the following services:

1. [JPal](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jpalapp/jpal-worlds-first-smart-synagogue-platform) (most promising, in development)
2. Minyan Now (Rusty)
3. GoDaven (unreliable)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Amit! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called MinyanNow, you can set the time and the place and get alert if someone calling for a minyan in your area.

I don't sure if enough people have installed this app.

https://www.rustybrick.com/iphone-minyan.php

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Omer! Thanks for the answer.