# Is there a "Jew" P.S. app for Android or iPhone?

Tags: technology, travel, minyan

I know that there are various minyan-finding sites like godaven.com They tell you the location and times of the closest shul to where you are located.

Is there an app that can locate Jews who are already on the road? For example, you're driving on a U.S. interstate and you know there is a rest-stop ahead. You'd like to either form a minyan or find someone who is about to form a minyan. Is there an app where people could subscribe to receiving notifications that a minyan is about to form near your location?

If you know of any, please indicate which O.S. it works on.

Comment: dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85882/davening-with-a-minyan-in-china

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rustybrick makes such an app for both Android and iOS. Here are the links:
[iOS](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/minyan-now-create-minyan-anywhere/id881011426?mt=8&at=11l4Pn) [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rustybrick.adhocminyan)

Here is a description from their site:

> Minyan Now For iOS & Android
>
> Minyan Now lets you quickly create a minyan, a group of 10 Jewish
>   males, where ever you may be, at any time of the day.
>
> Those who download Minyan Now will be able to request to form a Minyan
>   within the next hour or so. You specify the time and location and it
>   will alert other Jewish men in the area about the Minyan. After 10
>   respond that they are able to make the Minyan, the Minyan will be
>   formed and you can daven.
>
> This works great at airports, train stations, sports events, and other
>   areas where there are likely 10 or more Jewish men, but no official
>   shul or synagogue in the area.
>
> This is cross platform and works with other platforms. It is also
>   integrated into the RustyBrick Siddur.
>
> Note: You must enable location services for this to work. The default
>   distance to be notified of a Minyan is 1 mile, you can change this
>   distance within your settings.

Comment: Thank you. To you and any other readers - if you have used this, please breifly comment on what you like / dislike about it.

Comment: @DanF Sorry, never used it. I'm usually in the NY Metro area and have no need for this app. It would only work if you have a large user base.

Comment: "I'm usually in the NY Metro area" - We prob. pass each other sometime during the day, and don't even know it. If you see a person wearing a brown "Jerusalem" baseball cap, say "Shalom".

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems similar to the question I posted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85882/davening-with-a-minyan-in-china?noredirect=1&lq=1). I'll just mentioned some of the answers that seemed more interesting to me.

**1.** [[JPal](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jpalapp/jpal-worlds-first-smart-synagogue-platform)] this seems like a very promising app however the campaign was never fully funded on Kickstarter so I don't know if the developers are still planning on releasing it to the public. However, based on the description it seems very useful since you could track participants in real time, get notified about Minyanim nearby, view Minyan details (number of participants, *Nusach* etc) using an interactive map. Once again, please contact the developers to know if they are releasing this app anytime soon.

[image: JPal]

**2.** Rustybrick (active but features older interface and design)

**3.** GoDaven (I think this site is more geared for permanent Minyanim, not Minyan on the go type of thing)